# Wrong Date in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to get today's date in SuiteScript, when I type `var tDate = new Date();` it shows me yesterday's date while debugging. I checked settings, there I couldn't see anything wrongly.

I am editing to this question. Most confusing thing is sometimes  `new Date ()`  shows correct Date without any changes. No idea why it's acting like this. I added result of 'new Date()' as a picture right below.

In the first picture I captured on 1st of February, that shows me 31st of January which is wrong
[image]

In  the second picture I captured today, that shows me today's date which is correct.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`new Date()` will give you the current timestamp according to the timezone of whatever system is running the code. In your browser console, `new Date` will give you the current timestamp in local time; in a server-side script, `new Date` will give you the current timestamp according to the timezone of your NetSuite data center.

How are you running this code, and what timezone are you yourself in?

Comment: Yea and to be clear, it also depends on what kind of script it is. A client script will run browser. A user event or scheduled script run on the server. You would want to know where the server is that you are on. For me it is in Pacific Standard Time (PST).

Comment: Im using scheduled script. My time zone  seted to (GMT+03:00), as is should be.   The confusing thing is sometimes `new Date()` shows the right Date, No idea why it is acting like this.

Comment: In a Scheduled Script, your time zone preference will have no effect on what `new Date()` returns. Your code is running on NetSuite's server, so the time zone set in *that* environment will determine the time zone of `new Date()`.

Comment: From your second screenshot, the timezone on the server is PST (GMT-8). Since your local timezone is GMT+3, dates coming from NetSuite's server will always be 11 hours behind your local time. If you run your code after 11 AM local time, you will see the correct date, but if you run it before 11 AM local time, you will see yesterday's date.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh  yeah you are right. I realized it the time returns GMT-08:00. Is there any way to use Company Information date?